# Bootstrap carousel custom css not working with id

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my css for my carousel to override bootstrap when I use an id or specific class selector.

When I use (e.g.) `.carousel-inner .active.left` it works perfectly -> [here](http://www.bootply.com/GTYQfDiIsW)

However, I only want to target `#carousel` because I am trying to use multiple carousels on the same page, but when I use (e.g.) `#carousel .carousel-inner .active.left` it stops working -> [here](http://www.bootply.com/9cQb8pn7oE)

I have isolated the issue to being a problem with my css, but I just can't work out why it isn't working.

Comment: Both of your code examples are identical. Other that they seem to be working: You are hiding the left/right controls. Why are you using CSS for that? Just leave the controls out in the HTML.

Comment: @RoToRa oops! I have now updated the 2nd bootply to show the difference. You're right, it looks like I can just remove the controls from my html, however, that wasn't really my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying what seems like everything, I finally found my solution:

I needed to add

```
#carousel .carousel-inner .next.left, 
#carousel .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    left:0;
}
```

Evidently by using the id it was overriding this style set by bootstrap's css, and so I need to put it back in.

Also thanks to RoToRa for pointing out that I can remove the controls in the html rather than hiding them in css.

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/qu8v9NXWzu)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to have **!important** to override the css:

```
#carousel .carousel-control.left!important, #carousel .carousel-control.right!important {
    background-image:none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/1Fdenz6jQ2

Comment: I have updated my question as the bootply wasn't showing the difference I wanted to highlight